# Does a cone require its object to be in its diagram?

Tags: category-theory

[Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists](https://books.google.com/books?id=ezdeaHfpYPwC&lpg=PA27&dq=Let%20C%20be%20a%20category%20and%20D%20a%20diagram%20in%20C.%20A%20cone%20for%20D%20is%20a%20C-object%20X&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q&f=false) says

> Let $C$ be a category and $D$ a diagram in $C$. A cone for  $D$ is a
>   $C$-object X  and arrows $f_i  : X  \to  D_i$ (one for each object
>   $D_i$ in $D$),  such that for each arrow $g$ in $D$, the diagram
>   commutes
>
> [image]

Does a cone  require its object $X$ to be an object in the diagram $D$, or just in $C$?

Thanks.

Comment: $X$ does not need to be an object in $D$. You can imagine $D$ as the base of a geometric cone, and $X$ as the tip of that cone.

Comment: Allow me to borrow the precise definition from Tom Leinster's book Basic Category Theory. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category and $\mathbb{I}$ be a small category. Then any functor $D :\mathbb{I} \to \mathscr{C}$ is called a **diagram** in $\mathscr{C}$ of **shape** $\mathbb{I}$. A **cone** on $D$ is an object $X \in \mathscr{C}$ together with a family of maps $(f_{I}: X \to D(I))_{I \in \mathbb{I}}$ of maps in $\mathscr{C}$ such that for all maps $u: I \to J$ in $\mathbb{I}$, we have $ f_J = D(u) \circ f_I$.

Comment: Typo: wrote "of maps" twice.